# How to store object relationships in Lucene?

Tags: indexing, lucene, entity-relationship, relationship

What is the best way to store the object relationships in lucene? I need to be able to read them back easily and fast. Currently they are not stored in the lucene index and reading them from DB is slow.

Comment: Can you be a tad more specific? What is the lifetime of the index / objects? (Are the objects / indexes persisted across multiple application runs?) Are all related objects stored in Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to add all of the objects that you wish to reference in a large hashtable / dictionary and store the object key in the Lucene index.

(I may have used some .Net specific terminology there, but I assume that the same concept can be applied to whatever language you are using)